# How to display Telerik RadWindow from code-behind of UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

The following is the code I am using to display popup window of Telerik(Radwindow) in aspx page. It successfully displays the window with the below current code.

How can I display popup window from ASP.NET Usercontrol?

```
RadWindowManager windowManager = new RadWindowManager();
RadWindow window1 = new RadWindow();

window1.NavigateUrl = "Window1.aspx";
window1.ID = "RadWindow1";
window1.VisibleOnPageLoad = true; // Set this property to True for showing window from code   
windowManager.Windows.Add(window1);
this.form1.Controls.Add(window1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, of course, but there are two issues with this approach:

- the user control will have to know about the window manager and window on the master page, traverse the controls hierarchy and find them
- if you add the entire snippet to the user control you will end up with several window manager instance and this can play a few tricks on you (see [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/troubleshooting/wrong-radwindow-is-opened)).

So, think about the following ideas:

- add a RadWindow instance to the user control (not a RadWindowManager) and use that alone. Read [this article](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/troubleshooting/opening-from-the-server) to register a script from the server in order to open it and [this article](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/details/using-dynamic-unique-names-for-javascript-functions) on making the JS functions you may need unique per user control.
- open the RadWindow purely from the client-side as shown [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/getting-started/opening-windows). You can [register a JS function from the server](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/troubleshooting/executing-javascript-code-from-server) that will pass the parameters you need (URL, modality, whatever)

Here is a sample implementation of one of the ideas (that I would go with) based on your comment:

**Master page**

```
        <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadWindowManager>
        <script>
            function openDialog(url, modal, width, height) {
                if (radopen) { //if not, there is no RadWindowManager on the page, add an else{} block to use window.open() or other logic
                    var wnd = radopen(url, null);
                    wnd.set_destroyOnClose(true);
                    //add checks here in case parameters have not been passed
                    wnd.setSize(width, height);
                    wnd.center();
                    wnd.set_modal(modal);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

**User control markup**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="open RW" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" />
```

**Use control code-behind**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool flag = true;
    if(flag)
    {
        string script = string.Format("function f(){{openDialog('{0}', {1}, {2}, {3});Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}}Sys.Application.add_load(f);",
                                     "the-page.aspx",
                                     "true",
                                     600,
                                     400);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "someKey", script, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. I am having UserControls and Master pages. I need to display RadWindow from Server Side only. On click of save button some calculations are done and if it does not meet the save conditions, I need to dynamically display the Telerik RadWindow. I agree with you. Could you please provide me a simpler solution?

Comment: I added a sample reusable implementation example that I would have done in such a case. Of course, refactor and tweak a bit, it is just a sample

Comment: Great. But why I should touch the master page? Can it be done in the aspx page that is hosting the user control? Eagerly waiting for your reply.

Comment: It can, of course, but I just put together the common functions that tackle opening a generic dialog, because like that it can be reused everywhere. As I said, refactor according to your setup.